# Prove that a normal subgroup $K$ is characteristic in a finite group $G$ if $\gcd(|K|, |G/K|) = 1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is a part of an exercise $2.2$ on a page $203$ in a book "Algebra: Chapter 0" by P.Aluffi.

Let $K$ be a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$, and assume that $|K|$ and $|G/K|$ are relatively prime. Prove that $K$ is characteristic in $G$.

So we need to show that $\forall \phi \in Aut(G) \ \ \phi(K) \subseteq K$ assuming $|G| \in \mathbb{N}, \forall g \in G \ \ \ gNg^{-1} = N$ and $\gcd(|K|,|G/K|) = 1$.

Any hints?

Comment: This is now a (multi-)duplicate: [if $(|N|,[G:N])=1$, then $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $|N|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364847/if-n-gn-1-then-g-has-a-unique-subgroup-of-order-n)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider the image of $\phi(K)$ under the natural projection $G \to G/K$ .

Solution:

> The order of the image of $\phi(K)$ under the natural projection $G \to G/K$ is s divisor of both the order of $\phi(K)$ (which is the same as the order of $K$) and the order of $G/K$ and so the image is trivial. This means that $\phi(K) \subseteq K$.

Comment: I was thinking about the same, but I could not see the following: why the order image of $\phi(K)$ in $G/K$ divides the order of $K$?

Comment: I see: if $\pi$ is the natural projection, then $\phi(K)/(\ker \pi \cap \phi(K))\cong \pi(\phi(K))$, and so $|\phi(K)|=|\pi(\phi(K))|\cdot |\ker \pi \cap \phi(K)|$

Comment: Another way to see it is that since $\pi$ is a homomorphism and $\phi(K)\le G$, then $\pi(\phi(K))\le G/K$, which means that $\lvert \pi(\phi(K)) \rvert$ divides $\lvert G/K\rvert$.

Comment: @DaríoG Yes, by the first isomorphism theorem, the order of the homomorphic image of a group always divides the order of the group.

Answer (score 0):

for x in K the order of $\bar{\Phi(x)}$ devise  bothe ordere of K and ordere of G/K so is the identity in G/K and so $\Phi(K)$ is inckus in K.

Answer (score 0):

For any $f\in \text{Aut}(G)$, $f(K)$ is also a subgroup, and by the second isomorphism theorem, $f(K)\cap K$ is normal in $f(K)$. Consider the group $$H=\frac{f(K)}{f(K)\cap K}=\frac{Kf(K)}{K}.$$ Then $|H|$ divides $|f(K)|=|K|$. Note that $Kf(K)$ is a subgroup of $G$, so $$|H|=|Kf(K):K|=\frac{|G:K|}{|G:Kf(K)|}.$$Thus, $|H|$ divides $|G:K|$. Therefore, $|H|=1$, so $f(K)=f(K)\cap K$, namely $f(K)\subseteq K$.